# ImportError: cannot import name 'load_learner' from 'fastai'

Tags: python-3.x, importerror, fast-ai

I'm new to `fastai`.

- fastai 2.7.5
- fastcore 1.4.5
- nbdev 1.2.10
- torch 1.12.0
- torchvision 0.13.0

```
from fastai import load_learner

learn = load_learner('export_2.pkl', cpu=False)

>>> ImportError: cannot import name 'load_learner' from 'fastai' (/home/daniel/miniconda3/envs/pdl1lung/lib/python3.9/site-packages/fastai/__init__.py)
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
from fastai.vision.all import *
```

```
conda create -n venv python==3.6.13
```

```
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

`requirements.txt`:

```
fastai==2.5.3
fastcore==1.3.27
python==3.6.13
```